# Comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions S

Tags: c++

I get this warning when compiling a source in c ++ with gcc in FreeBSD.

Could someone explain and help me solve the issue I'm having?

Following is a link to the entire source code, it was placed on pastebin because it contains 7000 lines of code. [Source char.cpp](http://pastebin.com/A238Lqh8)

Here is the warning message :

```
In member function 'void CHARACTER::PointChange(BYTE, int, bool, bool)':
```

Comment: You need to show us the declarations for `amount` and `exp`.

Comment: The error is clear, check the type of the variables (which you don't even show in the question)

Comment: A wild guess is that `exp` is declared unsigned.  In which case your `if` statement can never be true.

Comment: Can you give me the correct syntax to me, just replace it. I am beginner in c ++. I only managed to do Hello World program. For three days reading about c ++.

Comment: @HotLicks if amount is negative enough, exp < -amount can apply, so the statement can be very much true. The compiler could just guess and do the cast for you, which is highly probable. However it has to print out a warning...

Comment: The net-net on comparisons of signed/unsigned is that you should always cast to a common type to make your intent clear.  You can sometimes rely on the default rules, but they can surprise you.

Comment: For this question to be on-topic, it needs to have the relevant [mcve] included **in the question**. If all 7K lines are necessary, then it's just not a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: putting code on external size will make the question invalid when the link rots. And now it has really rotten. Always put code inside the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @KaliG s answer:

On the line **3065** you are declaring:
`DWORD exp = GetExp();`

Now what is a `DWORD`? Well, it stands for **double word**, and a "word" is 16 bits on this C++ implementation (Win32). It is a typedef and is actually an **unsigned integer**.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29

The other variable, amount is an argument defined as the type **(signed) int**.

So you are comparing a signed and unsigned integer - which causes the warning.
You can solve this by simply casting amount to an unsigned int (or "DWORD") since you have verified already that it is in fact positive.

So change the line to:

`if (amount < 0 && exp < (DWORD) -amount)`

This should work - but I have no idea how your method works other than that.

Sidenote: **Hungarian notation** is really ghastly stuff - so you should really dig into what the different type names they use actually are. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Sidenote 2: Don't use ALLCAPS class names... developers are used to think that those identifiers are constants, so you confuse other people who might read your code.

Sidenote 3: Read up on **2s complement** to understand what the ALU (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) inside the CPU is actually doing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Thanks Kali, it worked. Thanks for helping me. 

I finally understand what is DWORD :)

Comment: Now I only have 100 warning solved :) 
Of which 40 are like this which you helped you :)

Comment: As long as you learn how to deal with similar problems in the future that's progress =)

Answer (score 1):

From the error thrown, I would say it is because 'exp' is either an unsigned or signed variable while 'amount' is the opposite, hence the reason you get the comparison error thrown.

Please post the lines of code where you declare these variables. :)

(Verify if you declared either of these 2 variables as a signed/unsigned by mistake.)

Comment: I would like not to have to go through 7000 lines of code, please do some work and extract the pertinent parts out of the code. Just post the places where you declare the variables and/or anywhere you might of done a typecast to the variable.
We are here to help, not to do the work for you ;)
(And you could try fixing it with what I and others pointed out first to see if it fixes it)

Comment: I understand, thank you for trying to help me. 
What lines of code that called last.http://pastebin.com/7i5WJvJd

Comment: The line 71 is the line 3.088 .

Comment: A file of 7000 lines of code is way too long to be manageable... Do yourself a favor and write some proper unit tests and isolate the problem - void CHARACTER::PointChange(BYTE type, int amount, bool bAmount, bool bBroadcast) is too long and doesn't abide by Single responsibility principle. You are just asking for bugs with a method/class that long.

Comment: @Centril comment is spot on. Try to work with what I suggested and see if you get a positive result. Otherwise, nobody here is really going to go over 7000 lines of code to see where the issue comes from.

Comment: KaliG , are willing to help me solve the whole source? you may pay if you can tell me how I can contact

Comment: @KaliG yeah, and if we did, we'd be making Reby210 a dis-service since that teaches the developer not to be independent and learn how to find stuff like software engineers are supposed to.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very interested. I would love to help you fix your issues, but you need to make some efforts on your side. That is the best way you are going to learn anyway. Try to work with the hints we are giving you first. If it doesn't work, try to find the origin of the issue not just the line where the error is thrown and edit your original post with all parts of the problem without providing 7000 lines of code. StackExchange is a platform for help, it's not a platform for us to do the job for you, it would be a disservice anyway. :) Cheers!

@Centril Agreed.